# Format string of date in Smarty

Tags: php, date, templates, smarty

So I have these templates (`.tpl` files) being generated by Smarty. I have a variable `{$projects.laycanenddate}` which contains a date in the string format `12/24/2016` but I need it to be displayed in the format `24-Dec-16`.

I tried parsing it as a text with the code

```
    {php}
        $date = date_create($projects.laycanenddate);
        $projects.laycanenddate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    {/php}

<div class="right_olbl"> {$projects.laycanenddate} </div>
```

But it isn't working, since it's ignoring the `{php}...{/php}` as if it wasn't there. I read that there are also `<?php ... ?>` tags, but I'm lost as to which ones I should use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just assign Your date**

```
 $smarty->assign('date', strtotime('-1 day'));
```

**Format in tpl using smarty:**

```
{$date|date_format:'%e-%b-%y'}
```

Comment: Is that assignment made in the same `.tpl` file? I'm asking because I'm using nsmarty (a port of Smarty to Node.js) and I'm not necessarily working with `.php` files.

Comment: ya it should work  all of Smarty 3 (and Smarty 2) syntax is supported. by nsmarty

Answer (score 0):

{php} is no longer supported by smarty (it was a bad idea in the first place). Just use the date_format modifier. [Read the documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)